# Issue an error when section takes more than 2 pages

Tags: sectioning, errors

I have a need to make the build crash when a `\section` takes more than a single page (in a given environment). How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is "a section" now some range in an environment or a `\section`?

Comment: The 'sections' tag you added is the plural version of 'section' which is already an synonym of 'sectioning'. According with the tagging rules applied to this site I made it as well a synonym of 'sectioning'. That tag is for all sectioning macros like `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. Feel free to remove it if its doesn't fit for your question. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm talking about `\section` indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a label after the `\section` and after the end of it and then compare the pagenumbers e.g. using the macro `\vrefpagenum` of the `varioref` package. IMHO this is saver then using `\pageref` directly because it could include other material like hyperlinks, but I might be wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\checksection}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \vrefpagenum\@tempa{#1}%
    \vrefpagenum\@tempb{#2}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\else
        \GenericError{}{Section longer than one page!}{}{}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
   ....

   \section{Some section}\label{sec:some}       
   ...

   \label{sec:some-end} 
   \checksection{sec:some}{sec:some-end}

   \section{Other section}\label{sec:other}
   % Alternative:
   \checksection{sec:some}{sec:other}


\end{document}
```

You could also make an environment which places this labels at the `\begin` and `\end` and runs the check automatically. I might need to use `\refstepcounter{dummy}` (where `dummy` is some dummy counter) to make the `\label` produce the correct page number.

A problem with this solutions is that there might be error caused because of an outdated `.aux` file.

Comment: Interesting solution. Ideally though, I'd like to make it so that I don't have to add a tab at the end of each section. Also, wouldn't it be easier to just set a counter to `\thepage` at the beginning of the section and compare with `\thepage` at the end of the section?

Comment: @Raphink: No, the `\thepage` macro is not reliable (except in footers and headers), because when it is processed the page is not yet fully build and TeX doesn't know if the material it is used in is part of the current page or not.

Comment: @Martin: even if I build several times (I'm used to building 3 times to make sure references are fine after everything is positioned)? I'm using `\thepage` in a `\titleformat{\section}` command to display tabs on the side of the page, and I've had no problems with it. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @Raphink: Yes, `\thepage` simply adds the number of the `page` counter which is unaffected by reruns. Using `\thepage` might get you the correct number but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Martin: I plan on adding this check system to `\titleformat` because I need to check all sections. Using labels, I will end up with labels titled the same in all sections...

Comment: @Raphink: You could be able to place multiple labels to one `\section`. You could use a running counter to keep them unique. You could use e.g. `\label{section-\arabic{section}}`.